# Run Do...While Calculations Until Condition Is Met

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, do-while

I am writing a simple do...while statement using Javascript that's meant to look at the length of a decimal of a given input `num` and if the length of the decimal is greater than or equals to 1, to take the `num` and added it onto itself until the decimal length is equal to 0. Currently, it works for decimals with the length of 1, but anything greater, it stops.

The expected output, for example, when `num` is 8.75, should be 35, not 17.5.

The series should take 4 steps to reach 35.

```
8.75

17.5

26.25

35
```

Here's my code:

```
const num = 8.75;
var decimalLength = num.toString().split(".")[1].length;
let result = "";
let i = num;

do {
  i = i + num;
  result = result + num;
  newLength = decimalLength;
} while (newLength < 0);

console.log(i);
```

Comment: A string's length can never be `< 0` - your logic here is pretty flawed.

Comment: It's because `decimalLength` never changes anywhere in your code (i.e. you're not reassigning the value of `decimalLength` to the updated decimal length) hence it'll only execute once.

Comment: Sooo, I need to check a newLength instead the initial decimalLength??? Sorry, I'm new to coding so, I'm not that aware of best practices or best termolnology.

Comment: You could try converting the `decimalLength` constant to a variable and then reassign it to the new decimal length before the line containing the `while` and after the last line of your `do` block. (Additionally, as what AKX has mentioned, your logic of checking if a string has a negative length is not valid as strings only can have a 0 or positive length.)

Comment: Hmm, what would be a better approach to this? I also updated my code above trying to work in the new variable but it's still running the same. But ultimately I would need it to basically add the decimal onto itself until it becomes a whole number. Is there a known solution to this that's not converting to percents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's every answer combined. The advantage of this is that it has a 'fallback' for each kind of input. If there's a terminating decimal, Endothermic_Dragon's first method is sufficient. If it is a repeating decimal, then a new method that finds an answer definitively is sufficient. If it is not sufficient, then the continued fraction is used as a fallback.

Note that the only reason I included the continued fraction last is because of the errors it sometimes causes with smaller decimals. I would just 'fix' the method, but I don't understand how it works, so I used it as a fallback.

```js
//At the top so it is viewable
console.log(findMultiple(54.46333333333333)) //16339/300
console.log(findMultiple(8.333333333333333)) //25/3
console.log(findMultiple(14.05882352941176)) //Irrational
console.log(findMultiple(94.03820382038203)) //Irrational
console.log(findMultiple(623.0549383482724)) //1009349/1620
console.log(findMultiple(Math.PI)) //Irrational
console.log(findMultiple(13.000000221)) //1829587379722249/140737488355328
console.log(findMultiple(1.0000003333)) //1125900282105063/1125899906842624

//Main control
function findMultiple(num, interpretLiteral = false, epsilon = 1e-6) {
  if (num.toString().length < 17 || num % 1 == 0 || interpretLiteral) {
    return EndothermicDragonFirstMethod(num) //Terminating decimal
  }
  var checkRepeatingNum = CheckRepeating(num)
  if (checkRepeatingNum != false) {
    return Math.round(EndothermicDragonSecondMethod(num, checkRepeatingNum) * num) //Repeating decimal
  } else {
    return ScottSauyetFirstMethod(num, epsilon) //Continued fraction
  }
}


//Predifined functions

//GCD
function gcd(x, y){return !y ? x : gcd(y, x % y)};

//Check if digits repeat, if they do, return repeat period
function CheckRepeating(num) {
  var totalSearchLength = (num % 1).toString().split('.')[1].slice(0, -1).length
  var numTemp1 = (num % 1).toString().split('.')[1].slice(0, -1).split('').reverse().join('')
  for (var i = 1; i < Math.floor(totalSearchLength / 3); i++) {
    var numTemp2 = numTemp1.slice(0, 3 * i)
    var searchLength = i
    bool = numTemp2.slice(0, searchLength) == numTemp2.slice(searchLength, 2 * searchLength) && numTemp2.slice(0, searchLength) == numTemp2.slice(2 * searchLength, 3 * searchLength)
    if (bool) {
      return searchLength
    }
  }
  return false
}

//Terminating decimal
function EndothermicDragonFirstMethod(num) {
  var decimal = num % 1;
  var decimalPlaces = num.toString().split(".")[1]?.length || 0;
  var multiplier = 10 ** decimalPlaces / gcd(10 ** decimalPlaces, decimal * (10 ** decimalPlaces));
  return num * multiplier;
}

//Repeating decimal
function EndothermicDragonSecondMethod(num, repeatInterval) {
  var numArray = num.toString().split('.')[1].slice(-repeatInterval).split('').reverse()
  var restOfNum = num.toString().split('.')[1].slice(0, -repeatInterval * 3).split('').reverse()
  var counter = 0;
  var extraRepeat = 0;
  restOfNum.every(el => {
    if (el == numArray[counter]) {
      extraRepeat++;
      counter++;
      if (counter == numArray.length) {
        counter = 0
      }
      return true
    }
    return false
  })
  var repeatingPart = num.toString().split('.')[1].slice(-repeatInterval * 3 - extraRepeat, -repeatInterval * 2 - extraRepeat)
  var notRepeatingPart = num.toString().split('.')[1].slice(0, -repeatInterval * 3 - extraRepeat)
  var numerator = (parseInt(notRepeatingPart) * (parseInt("9".repeat(repeatingPart.length)))) + parseInt(repeatingPart)
  var denominator = (parseInt("9".repeat(repeatingPart.length)) * (10 ** notRepeatingPart.length))
  return denominator / gcd(numerator, denominator)
}

//Otherwise (irrational numbers or other)
function ScottSauyetFirstMethod(num, epsilon = 1e-6) {

  const contFrac = (n, d = 1, count = Infinity) =>
    count < 1 || d == 0 ? [] : [Math.floor(n / d)].concat(contFrac(d, n % d, count - 1))

  const bestApprox = (n, d = 1, c) =>
    contFrac(n, d, c)
    .reduce((a, n, i) => [
      ...a,
      {
        n: a[i].n + n * a[i + 1].n,
        d: a[i].d + n * a[i + 1].d
      }
    ], [{
      n: 0,
      d: 1
    }, {
      n: 1,
      d: 0
    }])
    .slice(2)

  const firstIntMultiple = (x, epsilon) =>
    bestApprox(x, 1)
    .find(({
      n,
      d
    }, i, a) => i == a.length - 1 || Math.abs(n / d - x) < epsilon)
    .n

  return firstIntMultiple(num, epsilon)
}
```

This results in accurate answers, no matter what in the world in the input is (even if it is a small decimal)!

Comment: I get this error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'gcd' before initialization`.  Can you tell me what sorts of value error in the Continued Fraction solution?  Just really small values?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I forgot to change the *constant* `gcd` to the *function* `gcd`. Updated!

Comment: WOAH! This is a BEAST! You and Scott are brilliant! I implemented the solution and it performs and calculates better than expected! I really appreciate you two and your brilliant minds because I would've never been able to achieve this. I'm studying the code and explainations because this is so awesome!

Comment: I'm just a teen with internet access, @King. Scott seems to be a university professor (given by his profile picture), so he's the actual brilliant mind. I would follow him but stack overflow doesn't have that option, sadly.

Comment: Not a professor, just a work-a-day programmer, but one with college degrees in Math.  I would still recommend only my original version, except maybe with the same tweak I added to my final one to check ratios rather than differences, if you need to handle small positive numbers.  Been fun working with both of you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use some fancy maths to get a more definitive answer that doesn't loop over and over again:

```js
const num = 8.75;
var decimal = num % 1 //Decimal part
var decimalPlaces = num.toString().split(".")[1] ?.length || 0; //Get decimal places

//GCD function
const gcd = (x, y) => (!y ? x : gcd(y, x % y));

//GCD between decimal and 1, need to make it whole number to get multiplier, so multiply each with 10^[decimal places]
//Get what's remaining when divided by 10^[decimal places] as well, to see what to multiply by to get whole number
var multiplier = 10 ** decimalPlaces / gcd(10 ** decimalPlaces, decimal * 10 ** decimalPlaces)

//Use log change of base property to get value in power of 2
var outputExponent = Math.log(multiplier) / Math.log(2)
//Multiply number by multiplier
var outputValue = num * multiplier

console.log(outputExponent) //Power of 2 to multiply by to get whole number
console.log(outputValue) //The whole number itself
```

Comment: The solution is exactly what I needed with the math required!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Hey! Hope you're still there, any way to fix the issue when it cannot read property length of undefined? I seem to be getting this error for some values, not sure why.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what values you are trying? If it is an integer, then, well, it doesn't need any calculations since it is already an integer,

Comment: Try replacing `num.toString().split(".")[1].length` with `num.toString().split(".")[1]?.length || 0`. This just returns 0 in case the string is undefined (aka no decimal places).

Comment: Ah! Yes, that fixed it! Thanks! I was super confused, much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this actually meets the requirements, as it simply processes powers of 2.  If you were to start with `num` of `25 / 3`, then it would miss.

Comment: It would! But then again, you cannot get to a whole number if you start with `25 / 3` by doubling. In that case, you can just check if the power of 2 returned is a whole number.

Comment: Notice the `26.25` in the description of the steps: `[8.75, 17.5, 26.25, 35]`.  By "added it onto itself", the OP seems not to mean repeated doubling but repeated multiples of the original.

Comment: Yes, adding a number by itself is equal to doubling. In addition, OP just needs the output to be a whole number and does not really need the steps. I just added the power of two to show that it could also be done if needed.

Comment: Again, note the `26.25` in the question.  Or try, say, `25/3` for your input.  It may be that the OP only has powers of two to be concerned with, but I think this isn't as general as the question asked.

Comment: `26.25` works perfectly, but `25/3` does not (unsurprisingly), since javascript rounds that to a certain point and handles binary error. So, *technically*, it does work for `25/3`, or at least the output of `25/3` when evaluated.

Comment: Repeating decimals cannot be handled through native javascript alone - they are, if you will, a 'special' category of numbers inexpressible in value through conventional computing methods.

Comment: My point was that `8.75 + 8.75 //=> 17.5`, and `17.5 + 8.75 //=> 26.25`, then `26.25 + 8.75 //=> 35`.  We need to check if `26.25` is an integer.  Similarly `25/3 + 25/3 //=> 50/3` and `50/3 + 25/3 //=> 25`.  So that should return `25`.  In other words, as I read the question, it can be answered by answering this: "What is the smallest positive integer multiple of my input?"  My answer tries to do that.

Comment: I read it that way too. My answer attempts to find an exact multiple without repeating an unknown amount of times. Because of that, it has no `tol` like your answer.

Comment: I actually went for the same (or extremely similar) approach as you originally, but then recognized the huge amount of time it would take to execute for decimals with lots of digits. So, I made a much better one using GCD that can execute in significantly shorter time.

Answer (score 2):

This version uses a recursive function and a tolerance to deal with floating point rounding errors.

```js
const firstIntMultiple = (n, tol=1e-6, c = 1) =>
  Math.abs(n * c - Math.floor(n * c)) < tol ? n * c : firstIntMultiple (n, tol, c + 1)

console .log (firstIntMultiple (8.75))               //  35/4
console .log (firstIntMultiple (8.333333333333334))  //  25/3
console .log (firstIntMultiple (14.058823529411764)) //  239/17
```

It finds the correct version by multiplication by successive integers instead of successive additions, but it's the same idea.

We can easily replace the recursive version by an iterative approach, which might be useful for numbers which don't have a good rational approximation.  (Right now, passing `Math.PI` will run into recursion limits.)

That might look like this:

```js
const firstIntMultiple = (n, tol=1e-6) => {
  let c = 1;
  while (Math.abs(n * c - Math.floor(n * c)) > tol) {
    c += 1
  }
  return n * c
}
```

and for `Math.PI`, that would return `4272943.0000005495`, the first multiple of pi that is within `1e-6` of an integer.  And you can adjust the tolerance as needed.

### Update -- an entirely different technique

Another technique would take advantage of [the fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) that [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) offer a straightforward way to find the best rational approximations to a number.  We can use this to find the ten best rational approximations to `pi`, for instance like this:

```js
bestApprox (Math.PI, 1, 10) .map (({n, d}) => `${n}/${d}`)
// => ["3/1", "22/7", "333/106", "355/113", "103993/33102", "104348/33215", 
//     "208341/66317", "312689/99532", "833719/265381", "1146408/364913"]
```

And then, using those approximations, we can find the first one that is within some small distance from our target value.

The code might look like this:

```js
const contFrac = (n, d = 1, count = Infinity) =>
  count < 1 || d == 0
    ? []
    : [Math .floor (n / d)] .concat (contFrac (d, n % d, count - 1))

const bestApprox = (n, d = 1, c) =>
  contFrac(n, d, c)
    .reduce ((a, n, i) => [
      ...a, 
      {
        n: a [i] .n + n * a [i + 1] .n, 
        d: a [i] .d + n * a [i + 1] .d
      }
    ], [{n: 0, d: 1}, {n: 1, d: 0}])
    .slice (2)

const firstIntMultiple = (x, ε = 1e-6) => 
  bestApprox (x, 1) 
    .find (({n, d}, i, a) => i == a.length - 1 || Math.abs (n / d - x) < ε) 
    .n


console .log (firstIntMultiple (8.75))               //  35/4
console .log (firstIntMultiple (8.333333333333334))  //  25/3
console .log (firstIntMultiple (14.058823529411764)) //  239/17
console .log (firstIntMultiple (Math.PI))            //  353/113
console .log (firstIntMultiple (Math.PI, 1e-8))      //  103993/33102
```

I haven't tested for performance, but this should be reasonably good, especially for those number whose continued fractions contain large integers early.  (`pi` for instance is `<3; 7, 15, 1, 292,...>`  That `292` implies that `3 + (1 / (7 + (1 / (15 + 1 / 1))))` or `355 / 113` is an excellent approximation to `pi`, and in fact, it's good to six decimal places.

I don't know how helpful this is to the OP, but it shows that ancient math classes might one day come in handy!.  ;-)

### Update 2 - Now With More Explanation!

This version cleans up the issue in the second approach with small values, by checking not if the test value is within epsilon of the original value but if the *ratio* of the the test value to the original value is within epsilon of `1`.  It also has some minor clean-up and a smaller value for the default epsilon:

```js
const contFrac = (n, d = 1, count = Infinity) =>
  count < 1 || d == 0
    ? []
    : [Math .floor (n / d)] .concat (contFrac (d, n % d, count - 1))

const bestApprox = (n, d = 1, count = Infinity) =>
  contFrac(n, d, count)
    .reduce ((a, n, i) => [
      ...a, 
      {
        n: a [i] .n + n * a [i + 1] .n, 
        d: a [i] .d + n * a [i + 1] .d
      }
    ], [{n: 0, d: 1}, {n: 1, d: 0}])
    .slice (2)

const isClose = (x, y, ε) =>
  y == 0 ? x < ε : (x / y > 1 - ε && x / y < 1 + ε)

const firstIntMultiple = (x, ε = 1e-8) => 
  bestApprox (x, 1) 
    .find (({n, d}, i, a) => i == a.length - 1 || isClose (n / d, x, ε)) 
    .n


console .log (firstIntMultiple (8.75))               //  35/4
console .log (firstIntMultiple (8.333333333333334))  //  25/3
console .log (firstIntMultiple (14.058823529411764)) //  239/17
console .log (firstIntMultiple (Math.PI))            //  103993/33102
console .log (firstIntMultiple (Math.PI, 1e-6))      //  353/113
console .log (firstIntMultiple (13.000000221))       //  58823532/4524887
console .log (firstIntMultiple (1.0000003333))       //  3000301/3000300
console .log (firstIntMultiple (1234/987654321))     //  6/4802209
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

#### Explanation

The main function here is still `firstIntMultiple`, and it's fairly simple, just searching the results of `bestApprox` for a rational approximation that is close enough to our target number and then returning the numerator of that result.  "Close enough" is determined by `isClose`, which checks if the ratio of the two numbers is between `1 - ε` and `1 + ε`, where `ε` is an optional parameter that defaults to `1e-8`.

So the question is how `bestApprox` works.  For that, we need to discuss [Continued Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).  I cannot do them justice here, but hopefully I can describe enough to give a feel for them.

Here is a repeating infinite simple continued fraction:

```
                    1
1 + ---------------------------------
                      1
     2 + ----------------------------
                        1
          2 + ---------------------
                          1
                2 + ---------------
                            1
                      2 + ---------
                                 
                            2 + ...
```

It's a continued fraction because we keep nesting fractions in the denominators of other fractions.  It's infinite because... well because it continues on infinitely - in an obvious manner.  It's simple because all
the numerators are `1`s.

It's not hard to show with a little algebra that this represents the square root of `2`.

This will usually be abbreviated with a notation like:

```
<1; 2, 2, 2, 2, ...>
```

where all the values are integers, and after the first one, all are positive.

These have a few advantages.  All rational numbers have a finite representation as a continued fraction, and all quadratic numbers have a repeating infinite pattern.  But more importantly, the prefixes of these continued fractions contain the best rational approximations to a number.  (The proof is not terribly difficult, and should be something non-mathematicians can follow.  But I won't try it here.)

By this, I mean that these numbers:

```
<1;>            //=> 1
<1; 2>          //=> 3/2
<1; 2, 2>       //=> 7/5
<1; 2, 2, 2>    //=> 17/12
<1; 2, 2, 2, 2> //=> 41/29
...
```

Are successively better approximations to `sqrt(2)`, and there are no better approximations available except with higher denominators.  That is, for example, among denominators greater than `12` and less than `29`, there are not better approximations to `sqrt(2)`.

So by calculating the partial continued fraction for a number, we can find all the best approximations, and eventually find one that gets the multiple we're looking for.

Now we need to know how to calculate these continued fractions and then how to turn them their partials into rational numbers.  Luckily, both are pretty easy.

To find the elements of a continued fraction, all we need to do is find the floor of the number, add that to our list, then continue with the reciprocal of the remainder.

If we started with `27/11`, then the first element would be `floor(27/11)` or `2`; the remainder is `5/11`, which has the reciprocal of `11/5`,  The next digit would be the floor of that, which is `2`, with a remainder of `1/5`, whose reciprocal is `5` with no remainder.  And so `27/11` can be written as `<2; 2, 5>`.

If we started with `pi`, then our first element would be `3`, then we'd continue with the reciprocal of `0.14159265358979312`, which is `7.062513305931052`, and the next element would be `7`.  Taking the reciprocal of the remainder, we get `15.996594406684103`, and the next element is `15`.  The reciprocal of that remainder is `1.0034172310150002`, so the next element is `1`.  Then the reciprocal of the remainder gets much larger, at `292.63459087501246`.  We could continue to get a result like:

```
<3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 3, 3, 2, 1, ...>
```

which has no obvious pattern.  But the high value of `292` tells us that `<3; 7, 15, 1>`, or `355/113` is an excellent approximation for `pi`.

The function `contFrac` does this algorithm just as described.

Now, to turn the partials into rational numbers, we can use a simple recursion.  In `<a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3, ...>`, the first approximation is `a_0`, which we write as `a_0/1`.  The second one is `a_0 + (1 / a_1)` or `(a_0 * a_1) / a_1`.  After that, we can find the `(k + 2)`nd value by this simple formulas: `n_(k + 2) = a_(k + 2) * n_(k + 1) + n_k`, and `d_(k + 2) = a_(k + 2) * d_(k + 1) + d_k`.

So for `<3; 7, 15, 1>`, we start with `3/1` then `22/7`, then our next value is `(15 * 22 + 3) / (15 * 7 + 1)` or `333/106`, and then `(1 * 333 + 22) / (1 * 106 + 7)` or `355/113`.  The code uses a little trick which extends the numerators and denominators back two steps so that we can use our recursion for every step and then simply slices those two value off the final result.

And there we have it.  By using the best rational approximations to a number, we can quickly find the smallest integer which, within a small tolerance, is a multiple of that number.

Comment: Check out my new answer, which discusses the pros and cons of our different answers!

Comment: Amazing explanation! I would upvote again, but unfortunately, I cannot do that.

Comment: Hey, question! I'm running into a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" within ```const contFrac = (n, d = 1, count = Infinity) =>```, with ```^``` pointing to ```n```, when working with larger integers. Any quick fix? Awesome update as well!

Comment: @KingMuze: I haven't seen that.  What sort of input is yielding it?

Comment: Seems to be when the input is Infinity or for example when I divide 17875903 / 3825454 and get = 4.672884055069019 and feed that in as an input. I have this implemented as part of a series of calculations, so I believe because of the number of times I may have to call and run the function, it causes the call stack error. Is it because of the array?

Comment: Let me alter my code a bit more, move the function around and see if it fixes it.

Comment: That example [seems to work](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20contFrac%20%3D%20%28n%2C%20d%20%3D%201%2C%20count%20%3D%20Infinity%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20count%20%3C%201%20%7C%7C%20d%20%3D%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20%5BMath%20.floor%20%28n%20%2F%20d%29%5D%20.concat%20%28contFrac%20%28d%2C%20n%20%25%20d%2C%20count%20-%201%29%29%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28contFrac%20%2817875903%2C%20%203825454%29%29%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28contFrac%20%2817875903%20%2F%203825454%29%29), whether as numerator and denominator or as their ratio. (With different answers due to rounding.)

Comment: Yeah, your code works perfectly, seems to be my code and how I have the functions set up. Calling the contFrac too many times.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the recursive function can't be placed within another function, which is kinda where I need it to be. I have to run the function as many times as required and its result determines if the function continues to run or stops when the result meets the condition. Not sure how to adjust the code so that it can work within another function.

Comment: Two things: First, it would not be hard to write `contFrac` iteratively and imperatively.  Second, it's unlikely that `contFrac` will add many more than a hundred frames to the stack trace, and it's not calling to anything else, so it seems unlikely to be your issue.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: You might be interested in this [iterative `contFrac`](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20contFrac%20%3D%20%28n%2C%20d%20%3D%201%2C%20c%20%3D%20Infinity%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20r%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20while%20%28c%20%3E%200%20%26%26%20d%20%3E%200%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20r%20.push%20%28Math.floor%28n%20%2F%20d%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bn%2C%20d%2C%20c%5D%20%3D%20%5Bd%2C%20n%20%25%20d%2C%20c%20-%201%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20r%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28contFrac%20%28Math.PI%2C%201%2C%2010%29%29).  It's the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Two competing answers. Which is the better one? There is no way of knowing until you test it out. So, that's what this new answer attempts to do.

These 'tests' (if you will) run each function 50 times, timing each iteration before clearing the console and logging the times' average.

### 8 Decimal Precision

#### Endothermic_Dragon:

```js
const num = 3.14159265;


//Function start
const firstIntMultiple = () => {
  var decimal = num % 1;
  var decimalPlaces = num.toString().split(".")[1] ?.length || 0;
  const gcd = (x, y) => (!y ? x : gcd(y, x % y));
  var multiplier = 10 ** decimalPlaces / gcd(10 ** decimalPlaces, decimal * (10 ** decimalPlaces));
  return num * multiplier;
}
//Function end


var times = []

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var startTime = new Date()
  console.log(firstIntMultiple().toString())
  times.push((new Date() - startTime) / 1000)
}

console.clear()
console.log((times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / times.length) + " seconds on average")
```

#### Scott Sauyet:

```js
const num = 3.14159265;


//Function start
const firstIntMultiple = (tol = 1e-8) => {
  let c = 1;
  while (Math.abs(num * c - Math.floor(num * c)) > tol) {
    c += 1
  }
  return num * c
}
//Function end


var times = []
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var startTime = new Date()
  console.log(firstIntMultiple().toString())
  times.push((new Date() - startTime) / 1000)
}

console.clear()
console.log((times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / times.length) + " seconds on average")
```

### 10 Decimal Precision

#### Endothermic_Dragon:

```js
const num = 3.1415926535;


//Function start
const firstIntMultiple = () => {
  var decimal = num % 1;
  var decimalPlaces = num.toString().split(".")[1] ?.length || 0;
  const gcd = (x, y) => (!y ? x : gcd(y, x % y));
  var multiplier = 10 ** decimalPlaces / gcd(10 ** decimalPlaces, decimal * (10 ** decimalPlaces));
  return num * multiplier;
}
//Function end


var times = []

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var startTime = new Date()
  console.log(firstIntMultiple().toString())
  times.push((new Date() - startTime) / 1000)
}

console.clear()
console.log((times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / times.length) + " seconds on average")
```

#### Scott Sauyet:

```js
const num = 3.1415926535;


//Function start
const firstIntMultiple = (tol = 1e-10) => {
  let c = 1;
  while (Math.abs(num * c - Math.floor(num * c)) > tol) {
    c += 1
  }
  return num * c
}
//Function end


var times = []
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var startTime = new Date()
  console.log(firstIntMultiple().toString())
  times.push((new Date() - startTime) / 1000)
}

console.clear()
console.log((times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / times.length) + " seconds on average")
```

Note that the functions will return slightly different results, due to slight differences in their inner mechanics. Endothermic_Dragon's answer tries to find the multiple which will return an exact whole number, whereas Scott Sauyet's answer attempts to find the multiplier which makes the number within the specified tolerance of a whole number.

These examples can be further scaled by adding more digits of pi on each and reducing the tolerance on Scott Sauyet's answer.

I was initially going to use `decimal.js` while testing this (https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/), however, it turned out to be quite slow on Scott's method - it took 5.1243 seconds to calculate each iteration, whereas on Endothermic_Dragon's it took 0.0002 seconds each iteration. Note that this was done with 10 iterations on w3schools.

All of this analysis can show two conclusions:

1. Endothermic_Dragon's answer is scalable and accurate on terminating decimals.
2. Scott Sauyet's answer consumes some time but produces an accurate answer. This is especially useful when dealing with decimals that do not terminate, whether they are irrational or repeating.

Also, here's an extra test, because why not.

### 15 Decimal Precision

#### Endothermic_Dragon:

```js
const num = 3.141592653589793;


//Function start
const firstIntMultiple = () => {
  var decimal = num % 1;
  var decimalPlaces = num.toString().split(".")[1] ?.length || 0;
  const gcd = (x, y) => (!y ? x : gcd(y, x % y));
  var multiplier = 10 ** decimalPlaces / gcd(10 ** decimalPlaces, decimal * (10 ** decimalPlaces));
  return num * multiplier;
}
//Function end


var times = []

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var startTime = new Date()
  console.log(firstIntMultiple().toString())
  times.push((new Date() - startTime) / 1000)
}

console.clear()
console.log((times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / times.length) + " seconds on average")
```

#### Scott Sauyet:

```js
const num = 3.141592653589793;


//Function start
const firstIntMultiple = (tol = 1e-15) => {
  let c = 1;
  while (Math.abs(num * c - Math.floor(num * c)) > tol) {
    c += 1
  }
  return num * c
}
//Function end


var times = []
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var startTime = new Date()
  console.log(firstIntMultiple().toString())
  times.push((new Date() - startTime) / 1000)
}

console.clear()
console.log((times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / times.length) + " seconds on average")
```

Comment: Do note how different the actual results are, though.  It's not so much a question of one being a little closer to the correct value.  `25/3` yields `25` in my answer but `133333333333333340` in yours.  I'm pretty sure that mine is correct, but the code might not need to handle cases where the numerator is something other than a power of 2, in which case, your answer looks fine.  The trouble with testing this against an irrational number is that there is *no* appropriate answer.

Comment: I might be tempted to create a more performant answer, as there's a useful technique with continued fractions, but it is less beginner-friendly.

Comment: Now I'm a bit intrigued. Could you expand on what sort of technique there is?

Comment: You can see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/CrossEye/77cf275ad5376ced2a7facac54fe2b7d) for an implementation that finds the sequential best approximations to a number.  That could easily be applied to this problem.

Comment: I updated my answer to include this option.

Comment: First off, let me put out there that I have no idea how your code works. However, I noticed that for small enough decimals, the code returns about the number itself or 0, which is not right.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem in working with additive tolerances. We could probably make that more sophisticated by testing ratios, but I'm guessing this is of more academic than practical purposes anyway.

Comment: If you read the beginning of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), and especially see the "simple continued fractions", where the numerators are all `1`, you might get a good feel for it.  My code simply takes a rational number and calculates the first `c` terms of the continued fraction for it.  That then leads us to a way to calculate the best rational approximations.  Then it should be clear, as we just search for the first one within our tolerance and return its numerator.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting idea. Thanks, I learned a lot!

Comment: I tried to adapt your answer and 'compile' everything into a more time-efficient answer. Check it out!

Comment: Updated my answer with an attempt at a more solid explanation.  I would not likely use these versions, as they require a fair bit of code for a simple problem.  But if that code was a hot spot in the system and required optimization, this might be a useful technique.  But the underlying math of finding the best rational approximations using simple continued fractions is pretty interesting and occasionally quite useful.